# finding min, max, and average of linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, max, min

I have a program in which I'm supposed to build functions using linked lists to perform a variety of tasks. Currently, I am having an issue finding the min and max value of the linked list. For some reason when both come out to be the highest which digit which is 9, and when I try to find the average of the list, it still comes out as 9.

additionally, I think it's interfering with my pop function which is supposed to delete the last item, but  when I try to work it by sections one part wont work until he previous section is running for whatever reason.

here is my header

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H


class LinkedList
{
    private:

        struct Node
        {
            int data;
            Node *next;
        };

        int size;
        Node *head, *tail;

    public:
        LinkedList();
        ~LinkedList();

        // misc
        void display();

        // sorting and searching
        // reverse --> sorting in descending
        int linearSearch(int key);
        void sort();
        void reverse();

        // various math
        int min();
        int max();
        int mean();

        // adding
        void append(int num);
        void insert(int num, int pos);

        // removing
        void pop();
        void remove(int pos);
};

#endif // LINKEDLIST_H
```

the header's source file

```
#include "linkedlist.h"



LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
    size = 0;
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
    if(head != nullptr)
    {
        Node *temp;

        while(head != nullptr)
        {
            temp = head->next;

            // deletes head
            delete head;

            // goes to next element
            head = temp;
        }
    }
}

void LinkedList::display()
{
    Node *temp = head;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << temp->data << "\t";

        temp = temp->next;
    }

    cout << endl;
}

void LinkedList::append(int num)
{
    // list is empty
    if(head == nullptr)
    {
        head = new Node;

        head->data = num;
        head->next = nullptr;

        // sets tail to head
        tail = head;
    }

    else
    {
        // creates new node
        Node *temp = new Node;

        // sets new node data
        temp->data = num;
        temp->next = nullptr;

        // sets previous tail link to new node
        tail->next = temp;

        // sets this node to new tail
        tail = temp;
    }

    // increments size
    size++;
}

void LinkedList::pop()
{
    if(size > 1)
    {
        Node *temp = head;

        // loops to node before tail
        while(temp->next->next != nullptr)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        // deletes tail
        delete tail;

        // sets new tail
        tail = temp;
        tail->next = nullptr;
    }

    // if there's only one item
    else if(size == 1)
    {
        Node *temp = tail;

        // head and tail are now null
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;

        // deletes node
        delete temp;
    }

    size--;
}



void LinkedList::insert(int num, int pos)
{
    if(pos ==0)
    {

        Node *temp=new Node;
        temp->data=num;
        temp->next=head;
        head=temp;
    }

    if(pos>1)
    {
        Node *pre=new Node;
        Node *cur=new Node;
        Node *temp=new Node;
        cur=head;
        for(int i=1;i<pos+1;i++)
        {
          pre=cur;
          cur=cur->next;
        }
        temp->data=num;
        pre->next=temp;
        temp->next=cur;
    }



    size++;

}

int LinkedList::linearSearch(int key)
{
    Node *temp = head;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(temp->data == key)
        {
            return i;
        }

        temp = temp->next;
    }

    return -1;
}

int LinkedList::max()
{
    int max = INT_MIN;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        while (head != NULL)
        {
                if (head->data < max)
                    max = head->data;
                head = head->next;

        }

     }

}

int LinkedList::min()
{
    int min = INT_MAX;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        while (head != NULL)
        {
                if (head->data < min)
                    min = head->data;
                head = head->next;

        }

     }
}

void LinkedList::reverse()
{
    Node* temp = head;

    // Traverse the List
    while (temp) {
        Node* min = temp;
        Node* r = temp->next;

        // Traverse the unsorted sublist
        while (r)
        {
            if (min->data < r->data)
                min = r;

            r = r->next;
        }

        // Swap Data
        int x = temp->data;
        temp->data = min->data;
        min->data = x;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

void LinkedList::remove(int pos)
{
    Node *temp = head;

    if(pos ==0)
    {

        head = temp->next;
        free(temp);
    }

    if(pos>1)
    {
       for(int i=0; temp!=NULL && i<pos-1;i++)
       {
           temp=temp->next;
       }

       temp->next = temp->next->next;
       free(temp->next);
       temp->next = temp->next;
    }



    size--;
}

int LinkedList::mean()
{


        int sum = 0;
        float avg = 0.0;

         Node *temp = head; 
        while (head != NULL)
        {

            sum += temp->data;
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        // calculate average
        avg = (double)sum / size;
}

void LinkedList::sort()
{
    Node* temp = head;

    // Traverse the List
    while (temp) {
        Node* min = temp;
        Node* r = temp->next;

        // Traverse the unsorted sublist
        while (r) {
            if (min->data > r->data)
                min = r;

            r = r->next;
        }

        // Swap Data
        int x = temp->data;
        temp->data = min->data;
        min->data = x;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

And the main

```
#include <iostream>

#include "linkedlist.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    LinkedList nums;

    // adding through append
    nums.append(8);
    nums.append(6);
    nums.append(7);
    nums.append(8);
    nums.append(0);
    nums.append(9);

    // displays list
    cout << "List after append: " << endl;
    nums.display();
    cout << endl;

    // adding through insert
    nums.insert(1, 0);
    nums.insert(5, 4);
    nums.insert(3, 8);


    // displays list
    cout << "List after inserting: " << endl;
    nums.display();
    cout << endl;

    // testing searching
    cout << "Testing linear search:" << endl;

    int pres = nums.linearSearch(7);

    if(pres < 0)
    {
        cout << "7 is not present in the list." << endl;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "7 can be found at location " << pres << endl;
    }

    pres = nums.linearSearch(5);

    if(pres < 0)
    {
        cout << "5 is not present in the list." << endl;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "5 can be found at location " << pres << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    // does math
    cout << "Minimum, maximum, and average before removing any items: " << endl;
    cout << "Min: " << nums.min() << endl;
    cout << "Max: " << nums.max() << endl;
    cout << "Mean: " << nums.mean() << endl << endl;

    // displays items reversed
    cout << "Items reversed: " << endl;
    nums.reverse();
    nums.display();
    cout << endl;

   // removing through pop
    nums.pop();
    nums.pop();

    // displays list
    cout << "List after popping: " << endl;
    nums.display();
    cout << endl;

    // removing through remove
    nums.remove(0);
    nums.remove(2);
    nums.remove(4);

    // displays list
    cout << "List after removing: " << endl;
    nums.display();
    cout << endl;

   // displays items sorted
    cout << "Items sorted: " << endl;
    nums.sort();
    nums.display();
    cout << endl;

    // does math
    cout << "Minimum, maximum, and average after removing items: " << endl;
    cout << "Min: " << nums.min() << endl;
    cout << "Max: " << nums.max() << endl;
    cout << "Mean: " << nums.mean() << endl << endl;

    // testing searching
    cout << "Testing linear search:" << endl;

    pres = nums.linearSearch(7);

    if(pres < 0)
    {
        cout << "7 is not present in the list." << endl;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "7 can be found at location " << pres << endl;
    }

    pres = nums.linearSearch(5);

    if(pres < 0)
    {
        cout << "5 is not present in the list." << endl;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "5 can be found at location " << pres << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the only parts I'm really struggling with is the max, min, and mean along with getting my pop function to actually initiate. I know that the pop function is written correctly but ever since I made the max and min it wont work now.

Comment: You have `if (head->data < max)` in both min and max. Also you don't have return in any of them.

Comment: If your compiler doesn't give you a warning for the definition of `mean`, turn up the warning level.

Comment: @maciek97x What do you mean? I have it set less than min in the min function.

Comment: @aschepler it's not giving me a warning

Comment: If you don't get any warnings you should change your compiler: https://wandbox.org/permlink/AjQBdhBXzUIkX4QO

Comment: @x-reaper in the max function you have `if (head->data < max)`.

Comment: @maciek97x I just changed that and it still comes out to 9

Comment: @x-reaper they should return some value.

Comment: @x-reaper Probably missing some compiler flags for that. Look at my answer, I have explained it there.

Comment: @x-reaper - Is it possible to specify the environment you are working in: Such as _Microsoft Visual C++_ , _Lynux gcc_ or _Borland C++_  which, I for example, used in my study years in College (I recon it is, for a long time now, no longer in use).

Answer (score 2):

There are several bugs that I have found in the code, and I have several remarks about it:

1. You should use spaces, and more consistently. There are places without enough spacing, and places with too many blank lines!
2. If you have two functions such as `insert` and `append` or `pop` and `remove`, they should use each other, meaning, `append` is just `insert(0)` (notice how I changed it in the code).
3. You are using double loops where it doesn't make sense (it isn't an error, but it is a bug!).
4. In the function `max`, you were doing the wrong comparison, asking if `max` is bigger than the current value...
5. You never return a value from `min` and `max`, which should at least create a warning in the compilation process!
6. You were creating empty nodes, and then you just put different values in their pointers, meaning that this new memory was still allocated (since there was no `delete`), but there was no way to access these anymore (this is a memory leak).
7. ***The biggest bug of all*** - When you loop in the `min` and `max` functions, you change the ***head*** of the list, which is a major bug (and that is why you got bugs ***after*** using this function). The solution is a simple but important lesson in C++ - ***Const Correctness***.

What is const correctness, and why is it important?

When you have a function, that does not change the ***state*** of your object, it should be declared `const`. This is our way to tell the compiler (and other programmers) that it mustn't change the state of our object. For example, `min`, `max` and `average` are classic `const` functions - they simply make a calculation that does not change the list, and return. If you had written `const` in the declaration of those, the compilation would have failed, since you actually ***changed*** the list (changing the head), although you shouldn't!

Moreover, when receiving objects into a function, whenever possible, you should make the `const T&` where `T` is a type. They will enforce that you are using only `const` functions of this type.

Also, I suggest compiling (at least on `g++`) with the flags `-Wpedantic -Werror'. The first adds some warnings about ISO C++ standards and the second makes all warnings into errors (and thus, your`min`,`max`and`mean` should not compile, since they don't return a value).

Here is the code:

```
class LinkedList
{
    private:

        struct Node
        {
            int data;
            Node *next;

            Node(int data_, Node* next_ = nullptr) :
                data(data_),
                next(next_)
            {
            }
        };

        int size;
        Node *head, *tail;

    public:
        LinkedList();
        ~LinkedList();

        void clear();

        // various math
        int min() const;
        int max() const;
        int average() const;

        // adding
        void append(int data);
        void insert(int data, int pos);

        // removing
        void pop();
        void remove(int pos);
};

LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
    size = 0;
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
    clear();
}

void LinkedList::clear()
{
    if (head != nullptr)
    {
        Node *temp;

        while(head != nullptr)
        {
            temp = head->next;

            delete head;

            head = temp;
        }
    }

    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;

    size = 0;
}

void LinkedList::display()
{
    Node *temp = head;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        std::cout << temp->data << "\t";

        temp = temp->next;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void LinkedList::insert(int data, int pos)
{
    if (pos == 0)
    {
        Node* prev_head = head;
        head = new Node(data, prev_head);

        if (size == 0)
        {
            tail = head;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Node *pre=nullptr;
        Node *cur = head;

        for(int i = 0 ; i < pos + 1; ++i)
        {
          pre = cur;
          cur = cur->next;
        }

        Node *temp = new Node(data, cur);
        pre->next = temp;
    }

    ++size;
}

void LinkedList::append(int data)
{
    insert(data, 0);
}

void LinkedList::pop()
{
    if (size == 1)
    {
        Node *temp = tail;

        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;

        delete temp;
    }
    else
    {
        Node *temp = head;

        while(temp->next != tail)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        Node* node_to_pop = tail;

        tail = temp;
        tail->next = nullptr;

        delete node_to_pop;
    }  

    --size;
}

int LinkedList::max() const
{
    int max = INT_MIN;
    for (Node* temp = head; temp != nullptr; temp = temp->next)
    {   
        if (temp->data > max)
        {
            max = temp->data;
        }
    }

    return max;
}

int LinkedList::min() const
{
    int min = INT_MAX;
    for(Node* temp = head; temp != nullptr; temp = temp->next)
    {
        if (head->data < min)
        {
            min = temp->data;
        }
     }

     return min;
}

int LinkedList::average() const
{
    int sum = 0;

    for(Node* temp = head; temp != nullptr; temp = temp->next)
    {

        sum += temp->data;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    return (double)sum / size;
}
```

Comment: `mean` doesn't return a value but OP uses `mean` in `cout << "Mean: " << nums.mean() << endl << endl;`

Comment: @ThomasSablik Yea, but it is declared `int mean()` and not returning is inconsistent with the declaration.

Comment: the last bug is the killer. :-) Also gcc is notorious for not noticing the absence of returns

Comment: @pm100 Actually the compiler has noticed, the problem is that he hasn't used the `-Werror` flag. Added it to my answer as well.

Comment: @Kerek - This is actually fixing the entire code and make it work (I assume this is some exercise given in some course such a CS 101) - I think a better way to learn, is showing x-reaper, how to debug. BTW There is another post with this code where you have a bug in `if (head->data < min)` which should be `if (temp->data < min)` (See x-reaper next question).

Comment: @Juv When it is all up to debugging, I won't put a code. But here, it is more about *how* to make the code, so it will be less error prone. Look at it like a CR.

Comment: @Kerek Note taken. I hope I did not sound patronizing. Sorry if I did.